# Cluster/Count entries by date by subquery

Tags: sql

I have a table that stores general information about meetings, e.g. the date. I'd like to know how many meetings customer x had in year 2018, 2019, 2020, etc.

My SQL knowledge is limited, hence I created a workaround with temp tables and JOIN, but I'm quite sure there must be an easier way. I gave it a try with a sub-query but it seems like that I'm missing something here. Unfortunately, I didn't find something useful with Google, but probably I googled for the wrong buzz words.

That's my code so far:

```
SELECT company_id, COUNT(id) AS '2019', (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM meetings WHERE created_at LIKE '2020%') AS '2020'
FROM meetings
WHERE created_at LIKE '2019%'
GROUP BY company_id
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, sqlserver...?

Comment: How do you define a customer? There is no such column in your query. Also, please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text. There is more than one way to understand what you ask for.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @cnt INT = 2018; --if 2018 is start year

WHILE @cnt < 2020  --if 2020 is ending year
BEGIN
--hear check how many meeting he did based on your database
SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
END;
```

hope i helped ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
select COUNT(id) as count, DATEPART(year,[created_at]) as[year] from meetings  group by DATEPART(year,[created_at])
```